# Avaloniaui Control Theme and Child Styles

Tags: avaloniaui

I have the following control theme where CustomBorder inherits from Border:

```
<ControlTheme x:Key="{x:Type controls:CustomBorder}" TargetType="controls:CustomBorder">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{DynamicResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource TextControlThemeMargin}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxThemeMinHeight}" />

    <Style Selector="^:pointerover">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="^:disabled">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxBorderBrushDisabled}" />
    </Style>
</ControlTheme>
```

In a different file I have the style:

```
<Style Selector="controls|CustomBorder">
    <Style Selector="^ > Grid, ^ > StackPanel">
        <Style Selector="^ > :is(TemplatedControl)">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5,0,0.5,0" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <Style Selector="^ > :is(TemplatedControl):nth-child(1)">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0.5,0" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4,0,0,4" />
        </Style>

        <Style Selector="^ > :is(TemplatedControl):nth-last-child(1)">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,4,4,0" />
        </Style>

        <Style Selector="^ > :is(TemplatedControl):nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
        </Style>
    </Style>
</Style>
```

Which modifies the borders of anything placed within the custom border. E.g it's allowing me to build composite controls with a singular border out of component templated controls.

I would like to merge the two files into a single file but I can't add the style to the control theme as it has child selectors and adding the style into the same resource dictionary as the control theme also doesn't seem to work.

Is there anyway of combining the two files, as currently the previews shown don't have both sets of logic, so I have to run the application to see the final outcome, e.g.

[Control theme preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEGSv.png)

[Style preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtsvD.png)